# Is it possible to do an animated border in react-native without third-party library?

Tags: javascript, react-native, css-animations

I'm trying to get an animated border radius for a 'validating' state.
One approach is to use a background gradient color, block out the 'box' with a pseudoElement, and rotate the background image on loop. ie: https://codepen.io/Chester/pen/QPoyjN

since react-native Stylesheets doesn't support pseudoelements; i'm trying to figure out how to get the same effect. Seems if i just set a borderradius and animate it, i'll get blinking/strobing top-left-right-bottom borders instead of a 'moving around the border' effect.
also `backgroundImage` style doesn't work, so can't set background to linear gradient...

```
backgroundImage:
      'linear-gradient(#399953, #399953), linear-gradient(#fbb300, #fbb300), linear-gradient(#d53e33, #d53e33), linear-gradient(#377af5, #377af5)',
```

any ideas?

tried [this codepen](https://codepen.io/Chester/pen/QPoyjNa)

and some pointers from [this article](https://medium.com/easyfundraising-org-uk/how-to-create-a-simple-loading-animation-in-react-native-typescript-without-libraries-and-with-7257551cd243)

I will try a version of setting a background image [like this](https://medium.com/@GroundControl/animating-gradients-in-react-native-8853dbd97d02) and putting my content right in front and smaller by `${borderWidth * 2}px`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49902089/animating-border-color-in-react-native
you need to check this